# Can't calculate distinct only on specified columns with SQL?

Tags: r, dplyr

When I run this code :

```
# get sample databases from: http://chinookdatabase.codeplex.com/
library(dplyr)
mydb <- src_sqlite("Chinook_Sqlite.sqlite")
Album <- tbl(mydb, "Album") 
ArtistIds <- Album  %>% select(ArtistId)  %>% distinct(ArtistId)  %>% collect()
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Can't calculate distinct only on specified columns with SQL
```

Why? How can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you could just do `ArtistIds <- unique(Album$ArtistId)`? It also might work if you don't give any arguments to `distinct`, though I haven't checked.

Comment: @Frank that does not work either. It returns `NULL`

Comment: Hm, okay. I guess the sql interface is different... Does `Album %>% select(ArtistId)` work? If so, perhaps `Album %>% select(ArtistId) %>% group_by(ArtistId) %>% slice(1)`?

Comment: `Album %>% select(ArtistId)` works, `slice(1)` does not work

Comment: Okay, last guess: `group_by(ArtistId) %>% filter( row_number() == 1 )`? The tutorial has some filtering in it, anyway: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/databases.html

Comment: nope, `Error in sqliteSendQuery(con, statement, bind.data) : 
  error in statement: no such function: ROW_NUMBER`

Comment: Hm, that tutorial really is insufficient when it comes to what does and doesn't work. Some sort of summarize should work, sounds like... `Album %>% group_by(ArtistId) %>% summarize(x=1) %>% select(ArtistId)` ?

Comment: That one works! I wonder how efficient it is compared to my initial approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to omit `distinct(ArtistId)` - the following seems to do the job:

```
tbl(mydb, "Album") %>%
select(ArtistId) %>%
distinct()
```

einar